# Access denied when you copy move and delete files in a fast way

Tags: c#, .net

thanks for spending your time reading this.
I've made a prove of concept about manage some files and folders.
The problem here is during the execution this logic throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException not always at the same time, I seems, for example, when the logic tries to move the file, the file is not created yet.
I can fix it put it Thread.Speep but I really don't like it at all.
Does someone have any idea ?
Thanks !!!

```
public class FileManager
{
    public async Task DoStuff()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var count = 0;
            while (count <= 100000)
            {
                Task.Run(() => File.Create("example.txt").Dispose()).Wait();
                Task.Run(() => File.Copy("example.txt", "test/example.txt")).Wait();
                Task.Run(() => File.Delete("example.txt")).Wait();
                Task.Run(() => File.Delete("test/example.txt")).Wait();
                count++;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you use separate files instead of the same one?

Comment: Yes, the problem is when you manipulate the same file. At some point it seems that the System.IO classes has and old info about the file system.

Comment: OK, so it works when you try something realistic and fails when you do something which is likely to break it. I suggest you don't do the latter. There *might* be something available in the overloads of file functions in kernel32 which you could refer to in [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/index.aspx) which solves it. Or you could try disabling write-caching on the drive, but expect your Windows performance to plummet.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for you answer. I have to manipulate the same files in the way that I've put in the example, the logic that I've put there is pretty realistic. I'll check pinvoke.net. Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps if you could do the create-copy-delete synchronously per file in one async routine it would help. Or just create-move instead.

Comment: Those calls to `Task.Run` are completely unnecessary as you're waiting for completion anyway.

Comment: Run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/sysinternals/bb896645) and then run your program. ProcMon could show you what went wrong and if any other process were interfering.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a virus scanner or similar system service interfering. Work around by renaming before delete:

```
var tmp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
File.Move("example.txt", tmp);
File.Delete(tmp);
```